# Is it possible to call the explicit interface implementation of the base class in c#?

Tags: c#, oop

I would like this program to compile, and then print the output below:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

public class FooBase : IFoo
{
    void IFoo.Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from base class.");
    }
}

public class Foo : FooBase, IFoo
{
    void IFoo.Bar()
    {
        (base as IFoo).Bar(); // doesn't compile
        Console.WriteLine("Foo added some behavior!");
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo() as IFoo;
        foo.Bar();
    }
}
```

Desired output:

```
Hello from base class.
Foo added some behavior!
```

Obviously, the code above doesn't compile, because it's an invalid way to use the `base` keyword. Is there a way to accomplish this, without changing the implementation in the base class to a non-explicit one?

Comment: Did you mean to make `Foo` inherit from `FooBase`?

Comment: @HansPassant: Sorry - I noted a typo in my example. `Foo` should both inherit `FooBase` and explicitly implement the interface; see the updated question. When casting `this`, how do I ensure that I get the base method?

Comment: @juharr: Yes, I updated the question while you wrote that comment :)

Comment: Also your methods are missing return types.

Comment: @juharr: Thanks - I did feel something was off :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply have the explicit interface implementation in the base class call a protected method in the class for its implementation.  This allows other derived classes to still call that protected method while still explicitly implementing the interface (and also not publicly exposing the interface's method through the type itself, which presumably is the actual goal).